# Excel logical formula to segregate items to different categories

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to prepare a excel report(say R) that has a column "Name" and another "Category". There are 3 categories to map all the entries in "Name".The entries in R go upto 500 often.

There is another master list(say M) that has the categories for all the 200 "Names". What I do is that I check the individual names in R and then search in M for the category. Then I write it in R, for all the instances of the particular name.

Please tell me a simple way to do this. Can I make use of IF function ? Will it be good to go when the number of "Names" is 200 ?

Comment: Please mock up some data and expected outcome and put it in your Original post using [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39979963/edit). It will be easier to understand exactly what your want.

Comment: I think (?) `Vlookup()` or `Index/Match` could help. But if you could show sample data, input and expected output, it would help to clarify.

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?